# Dynamically Resize Table Based on Text in Cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a dynamic table that changes size based on slicer selection, so sometimes the table may consist of 4 rows, sometimes, 7, sometimes 15, etc.

Regardless of the size of the table, the last row in column A will always equal "Retail Total".

My table looks essentially like this:

```
+--------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|     ColA     | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE | ColF | ColG |
+--------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Row1         | B2   | C2   | D2   | E2   | F2   | G2   |
| Row2         | B3   | C3   | D3   | E3   | F3   | G3   |
| Row3         | B4   | C4   | D4   | E4   | F4   | G4   |
| Retail Total | B5   | C5   | D5   | E5   | F5   | G5   |
+--------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

What I would like to do is have some VBA code that will resize the table depending on wherever "Retail Total" occurs.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ob As ListObject
Dim Lrow1 As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Table6")

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    Lrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    Do While .Cells(Lrow1, "A").Value = "Retail Total"
        Lrow1 = Lrow1 - 1
    Loop

End With

ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1)

End Sub
```

This code doesn't seem to work. The table keeps growing and does not stop at "Retail Total", so I was hoping for some assistance.

Comment: Shouldn't that `Do While` be a `Do Until`?

Answer (score 1):

I ran this code and it worked, except for an off-by-one error. I fixed it with:

```
ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1 + 1)
```

You should verify that the cell that contains "Retail Total" actually contains that verbatim phrase and not any leading or trailing spaces. You can test by putting this code in your immediate window and see if it comes up true:

```
? range("A5").Value = "Retail Total"
```

Replace A5 with whatever cell happens to contain "Retail Total" at the moment.

Comment: ahh this is so frustrating. I have another table above the one I am trying to resize (starting also in column A). Now when I run the code I get "Run-time error '13: Type Mismatch". Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Ok, I've modified the code a bit and it doesn't seem to be causing the error, BUT the code is not working as intended. There are about 10 extra rows being generated after "Retail Total". I am thinking this might have to do with data being above Table 6, also in column A...

Comment: Try this: ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1 + ob.range.row)

Comment: Does not seem to work. Even if there is nothing above my table, but i move my table down 4 rows (to a5 rather than a1), there will be 4 extra rows after "Retail Total". Actually if I do ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1 + ob.range.row) there are 9 extra rows. If i do ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1), there are 4 extra rows

Comment: Oops. Should have been  ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1 + 1 -
 ob.range.row)